# CSS Grid's fr unit is ignored when elements have white-space: nowrap

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>
        <h1>
            Element with a really, really, really loooooooooong title
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        Element 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS that I apply to it:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid > div h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

It seems that, however, the two columns do not have equal widths (`1fr`) as they should be (`repeat(2, 1fr)`) because of the `h1` in the first element having `white-space: nowrap`.

On the other hand, if you change the `grid-template-columns` property to:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, calc(50% - 1rem));
```

the grid then is visualized correctly.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qv8db9xm/) for those of you who want to reproduce this by themselves.

My question is why is `fr` being ignored because of the `nowrap` property of a child element? Is this expected behavior or is it an issue with CSS grid itself?

Comment: issue is css grid and flexbox have a min width/height equal to content, to fix this use `repeat(2, minmax(0,1fr))` to reset the min width or `min-width:0;` on the child elements

Comment: @ZohirSalak yes, it answers my questions, although I wouldn't consider it a duplicate. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider it a duplicate ? `why is fr being ignored because of the nowrap property of a child element` it is not being ignored because of a certain property on a child it's not being ignored at all `1fr` is the equivalent of `minmax(auto,1fr)` it's like saying put my content first then split the overall width between elements in this case there's no overall width it all been consumed by the first element.